# Regular Expression search to search exact match

Tags: javascript, regex

I am very much new to regex.

I have a scenario where I need to check the textbox value to the below format:

Format: AZnnnnnnn-nnn

The value has to start with "AZ" followed by 7 numerics and -(hiphen) and followed by 3 numerics

Can someone help on this

Comment: have a look at this: http://www.regexpal.com/
there you have the cheat-sheet to look up the meaning of the characters and you can also test your regex right there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
^AZ\d{7}-\d{3}$
```

---

```
^       -> start of string
AZ      -> AZ
\d      -> digit
{7}     -> exactly 7
-       -> hyphen
{3}     -> exactly 3
$       -> end of string
```

Comment: Thanks a lot baao. You have also made me understand :) Thanks again

Comment: Another doubt. Sorry for not raising it earlier.
Can i check two regex conditions for a single control. 
Scenario - AZnnnnnnn-nnn or nnnnnn
Either the above format or numeric of 6 digits for a single text box

Comment: Yes you can. Add the or operator and the second allowed expression. 
`^AZ\d{7}-\d{3}$|^\d{6}$` @user3750290